# Java/Postgres: Deadlock with Flyway clean

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-transactions, flyway

I have a scheduled task working (including writing!) on my PostgreSQL database:

```
@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = SCHEDULE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND)
public synchronized void doStuff() {
    // snip
}
```

And I do have a service to `Flyway.clean()` my database:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Transactional
    public void deleteDatabase() {
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();

        // snip
    }
}
```

Now every once in a while when deleting the database a deadlock occurs:

```
26-Jan-2017 17:15:57.174 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/foo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to drop "public"."bar"] with root cause
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 122 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 69572 of database 16388; blocked by process 97.
Process 97 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 69575 of database 16388; blocked by process 122.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:198)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:198)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:219)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLTable.doDrop(PostgreSQLTable.java:43)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SchemaObject.drop(SchemaObject.java:80)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLSchema.doClean(PostgreSQLSchema.java:84)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Schema.clean(Schema.java:148)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$4.doInTransaction(DbClean.java:182)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$4.doInTransaction(DbClean.java:180)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.cleanSchema(DbClean.java:180)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:130)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:1017)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:1013)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1361)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.clean(Flyway.java:1013)
    at com.acme.MyService.deleteDatabase(MyService.java:54)
    // ...
```

And I suspect the scheduler to be this other process. Now what? I'd say Flyway - as the more invasive operator, plus the one throwing the error - has to wait for exclusive access, but how do I achieve this in the most efficient way? Especially as both methods are @Transactional already... Will

```
@Transactional(isolation = SERIALIZABLE)
```

help? This isolation level seems to be the most restrictive... Or is it just the missing `synchronized` of `deleteDatabase()`? This dead lock is kind of hard to reproduce, so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: No, isolation levels won't help you with deadlocks. The only step to avoid deadlocks is to make sure every lock, which must be acquired on multiple objects should be acquired in the same order (i.e. that should never happen: transaction#1 locks obj#1 then obj#2 while transaction#2 locks obj#2 then obj#1).

Comment: On the other hand, what would you expect to be an acceptable behavior, when you purge the database while the same time trying to write it?

Comment: Obvious question :) Short answer: Everything which doesn't produce a deadlock. [EDIT: Damn, I always forget that Enter does not produce a line break on SO] While deleting the database I (obviously) do not care about the data being writen... but of course this doesn't stop the scheduler from doing so